# How Django authnetication works with SQL Server?

Tags: python, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, django

Just wanted to understand how exactly Python Django works with databases such as SQL Server or MySql.

For example, in ASP.NET WebForms, you'll have a `UserID` field from your custom `User` table that you link with the default `aspnet_Users` table. That's what connects your database to ASP.NET.

My question is how does it work in Django? How do I link registered users to my own database?

I hope this question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Django is consider a "batteries included" framework. Django has a robust ORM and build in system for user management. In specifics to users and authentication and authorization, Django has an out-of-the-box user model with fields for username, password, first name, last name, and email address; it also has facilities for groups and permissions. This can be extended using `AbstractUser`, or replaced entirely using `AbstractBaseUser`. More details can be found in the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/

Good luck.